# Dummy macro for ignoring beamer overlay

Tags: beamer, macros, overlays

I would like a dummy macro that ignores overlay specification (from beamer) when the code is copy-pasted into another class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\onslide}[1]{}
\begin{document}
   \onslide<3-10>{test}
\end{document}
```

I have some text from a beamer presentation that will be included into an `article` or `book` document, and since it's a lot of code, I'd like to copy-paste it without having to manually remove all the overlay specifications.

In the given example, my goal is a macro that prints only the word "test" and nothing else, ignoring the `<3-10>` specification.

Comment: Use `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`

Comment: `\usepackage{xparse}` and `\NewDocumentCommand\onslide{ D<>{} m }{#2}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments